# regex ismatch logic with special character

Tags: c#, .net, regex, special-characters

I know this statement should return false as expected

```
Regex.IsMatch("+", @"[a-zA-Z0-9]")
```

but why these statements matches although they shouldn't (from my understanding)

```
Regex.IsMatch("C++", @"[a-zA-Z0-9]")
Regex.IsMatch("C++", @"[a-zA-Z0-9]+")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are matches because you don't match the entire string. They will match the `C` in `C++`.

Use `^` and `$` to match the beginning and end of the string:

```
bool onlyAlphaNumeric = Regex.IsMatch("C++", @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"); // will be false
```